# python fastest and low resources solutions for web dev

Tags: python, django, web

i use python+django for my web projects and i love it for code readability and speed development. But now i want something **very fast**, **low cost for resources** and simple (minimalism) but in the same time code-readable as django.

1. Which DB backend to use?
2. Simple and fast ORM in django style?
3. Fast template system (with inheritanse)?
4. Web server written in python (i look at tornado or pyev for async server)?
5. cache system?

what do you recommend in this case?

Comment: Define "extremely fast".

Comment: There is no "fastest". Each solution generally lends itself better to one circumstance or another, but even then, a lot of it boils down to personal preferences. The important part is setting up your solutions *correctly*.

Answer (score 2):

Django will suit your purposes. (Unless you're doing high-frequency trading on the stock exchange).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/):

1. Take your pick
2. SqlAlchemy
3. Jinja2
4. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/ and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/
5. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

I personally tend to like Tornado a lot lately indeed.

Now, the question is: what are you looking for in a web framework? Fast development? Fast performance? Simple API? Active open source community?

Do you need a full stack framework like django or maybe you are good enough with a simpler environment? Will you serve dynamic pages or expose a REST api? If you are in the latter case, Django would not be my first choice, there are easier things to look at (I love [web.py](http://webpy.org/), FWIW).

Tornado sounds like a good choice if you are looking at async code too, anyway it's hard to give an answer without knowing more about your requirements.